# Pure Data - Get adc value in a particular duration

Tags: adc, puredata

I'm trying to get the `adc` values in says 50 seconds. I end up with the picture below[image]

I set up the `metro` as 50 which is 0.05 sec and the `tabwrite` size 1000. I got a list of values as below

[image]

But I feel it isn't right as I speak louder for a few seconds, the entire graph changed. Can anyone point out what I did wrong? Thank you.

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve. If you can, please expand your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `[metro 50]` will retrigger every 50 *milliseconds* (20 times per second).
So the table will get updated quite often, which explains why it reacts *immediately* to your voice input.

To record 50 seconds worth of audio, you need:

- a table that can hold *2205000* (50*44100) samples (as opposed to the default *64*)
- a `[metro]` that triggers every 50 seconds:

```
    [tgl]
    |
    [metro 50000]
    |
    | [adc~]
    |/
    [tabwrite~ mytable]

    [table mytable 2205000]
```